# Which theorem is applied in this integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

In my textbook, there is the following integral:
$\int \frac{x^3}{1+x^2}dx$, the next line is:$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}dx^2$, my question is what exactly did the author do?  Which theorem did he used? How did he increased the degree in the differential(how from $dx$, he got to $dx^2$)

Comment: $d(x^2)=2x\,dx$.

Comment: $dx^2/dx=2x$, so $dx^2=2xdx$, and you can substitute $x^3 dx$ into $\frac{1}{2} x^2 dx^2$.

Comment: They used $x\, dx = \frac{1}{2}\, dx^2$ because $\frac{dx^2}{dx}=2x$ (differentiate $x^2$ with respect to $x$). There shouldn't be a $-$ in $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960298/integrate-int-fracx3dx-sqrt1x2

Comment: One may see this as a change of variable: $u=x^2$, $du=2xdx$.

Comment: It could be clearer writing $\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\,d(x^2)$

Comment: Because the author would like to do the following:$$\int\frac{x^3}{1+x^2}dx=\int\frac{x^2x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{x^2\cdot 2xdx}{1+x^2}.$$ Did you notice $2xdx$? This is exactly the differential of $x^2$, in symbol, we write $$2xdx=d(x^2).$$ The author wrote $dx^2$ to mean $d(x^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a (often misleading) way to perform the substitution $x=\sqrt{u}$, $dx=\frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}$
$$ \int \frac{x^3}{1+x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{u^{3/2}}{(1+u)\,u^{1/2}}\,du=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{u}{1+u}\,du.$$
This clearly leads to:
$$ \int \frac{x^3}{1+x^2}\,dx = C+\frac{x^2-\log(1+x^2)}{2}.$$